# How to politely ask a person to be ready with the information they need to start?

Tags: email

I'm managing 2 teams A & B. Team A has dependency on Team B. My intent is to ask Team A to be prepared with what information they need from Team B. I'm struggling to put this on an email. Below is my effort -

*Dear Team A,
If we can be ready with the list of what information we need from Team B, then we can make a speedy progress right from the inauguration call.*

Comment: Looks fine. What specfic concerns do you have?

Comment: @JamesK I'm not convinced with the phrase "list of what information", "list of the information" etc. Are these correct phrases ?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the following:

> Hello Team A, Please prepare a list of the information you need from Team B before the phone call so we can proceed quickly after the call.

Comment: is the phrase "list of the information" correct ?

Comment: Yes.  The phrase suggests something like a bulleted list exists that describes the required information.  You could use the phrase similarly with groceries.  "Please prepare a list of the groceries we need for dinner."